# node-vibrant minimum colors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using `node-vibrant` for extracting colors from an image.
The problem is that (for images with more than 4 color) it extracts not always these 4 colors.
This is my code:

```
Vibrant.from(img.src)
    .quality(1)
    .clearFilters()
    .getPalette()
    .then((palette) => {console.log(palette)...
```

Example result:

> {Vibrant: e, LightVibrant: e, DarkVibrant: e, Muted: null, LightMuted: null, …}
> where for the example Muted and LightMuted are null.

I have tried and this repo `Vibrant.js` which is deprecated and they are saying to use `node-vibrant`. With older `Vibrant.js` for the same image, I am getting 4 colors:

> Vibrant #ea4138
> (index):26 DarkVibrant #aa1c1e
> (index):26 DarkMuted #040404
> (index):26 LightVibrant #eb494d

Is there a way to get minimum colors with `node-vibrant`?

I am using `React`.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the new version of *Vibrant.js*. I would recommend you to change your package.json to match a newer version (still on version 3). Could you please provide the image that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, I have used version `3.0.0`, `3.1.1` fixed the problem.